# Como puedo validar errores con javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando validar errores de un formulario html que envia data con Laravel 7, y queria mostrar mensajes de error especificos para cada campo.

Por ejemplo quería validar que en un campo donde se ingresa un valor numerico de un costo que el valor debe ser mayor a 0 y mostrar el respectivo mensaje.

```
<div class="card-body">
                <form method="post" action="{{ route('customers.store') }}" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                <div class="form-row">

                    
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="holding">Holding</label>
                        <select name="holding" id="" class="form-control" required>
                            <option value="">Seleccione el holding de la empresa</option>
                            @foreach ($customers as $key => $customer)
                            <option value="{{$customer->id}}">{{$customer->holding}}</option>
                            
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="company">Empresa</label>
                        <input type="text" name="company" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="legal_entity">Razon Social</label>
                        <input type="text" name="legal_entity" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="tipoCuenta">Tipo de cuenta</label>
                        <select name="tipoCuenta"  class="form-control" required>
                            <option value="">Seleccione el tipo de cuenta</option>
                            @foreach ($tipoCuentas as $tipoCuenta)
                            <option value="{{$tipoCuenta->id}}">{{$tipoCuenta->tipoCuenta}}</option>
                            
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="mobile_no">Telefono</label>
                        <input type="tel" name="mobile_no" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="country">Pais</label>
                        <select id="countries" name="country" class="form-control" required></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="state">Provincia/Estado</label>
                        <input type="text" name="state" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="city">Ciudad</label>
                        <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="address">Direccion</label>
                        <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="postal">Codigo Postal</label>
                        <input type="text" name="postal" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="cuit">Cuit</label>
                        <input type="text" name="cuit" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="website">Website</label>
                        <input type="text" name="website" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-md text-white" style="background:#030335e8">
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div><!-- /.card-body-->
```

Por ahora pude validar nada más que los campos deben ser completados al ser required. Pero no se como hacer una validacion logica y especifica para cada campo

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#myForm').validate({
    rules:{
      holding: {
        required: true,
      },

      company: {
        required: true,
      },

      legal_entity: {
        required: true,
      },

      mobile_no: {
        required:true,
      },
      email: {
        required:true,
        email:true,
      },
      country: {
        required: true,
      },

      state: {
        required: true,
      },

      adress: {
        required: true,
      },

      postal: {
        required: true,
      },
    
      cuit: {
        required: true,
      }
      tipoCuenta_id: {
        required: true,
      },
    },
    messages: {
        holding: {
            required: "Debe ingresar un holding",
        },

        company: {
            required: "Debe ingresar un nombre de empresa",
        },

        legal_entity: {
            required: "Debe ingresar una razon social",
        },


        mobile_no: {
            required: "Debe ingresar un telefono",
        },
        email: {
            required: "Debe ingresar un e-mail",
        },

        country: {
            required: "Debe ingresar un pais",
        },

        state: {
            required: "Debe ingresar un estado/provincia",
        },

        address: {
            required: "Debe ingresar una direccion",
        },

        postal: {
            required: "Debe ingresar un codigo postal",
        },

        cuit: {
            required: "Debe ingresar un cuit",
        },     

        tipoCuenta_id: {
            required: "Debe ingresar un tipo de cuenta",
        },           
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element){
      error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
      element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass){
      $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass){
      $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Esto lo hace laravel ,realmente quieres que solo lo valide jasvacript?

Answer (score 1):

Esto lo puedes hacer directamente con ayuda de php y del framework sin necesidad de hacerlo con javascript
en tu ruta `customers.store` puedes poner las validaciones en la función store

```
$request->validate([
    'holding' => 'required|max:255',
    'legal_entity' => 'required',
    'company' => 'required',
]);
```

y en tu formulario si no cumple la validación se retornan los errores en una variable

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```